# 'docker: command not found' with Jenkins build job on Mac

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running Jenkins on MacOS and I'm trying to use docker as agent with the following pipeline configuration ([Source](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/)):

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { image 'node:16.13.1-alpine' }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'node --version'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this pipeline, it works fine:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh '/usr/local/bin/docker --version'
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that docker command is not found. See console output from job build:

```
Started by user demo
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /Users/my_user/.jenkins/workspace/validate-digests
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker inspect -f . node:16.13.1-alpine
/Users/my_user/.jenkins/workspace/validate-digests@tmp/durable-d57c0dc0/script.sh: line 1: docker: command not found
[Pipeline] isUnix
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker pull node:16.13.1-alpine
/Users/my_user/.jenkins/workspace/validate-digests@tmp/durable-86c1139b/script.sh: line 1: docker: command not found
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 127
Finished: FAILURE
```

I've already searched and tried several solutions such as:
Manage Jenkins > Global Tool Configuration > Add PATH variable with `/usr/local/bin` as value. The problem with this solution is that I get: `sh: sh: command not found`
when building the job.

Any ideas on how to solve this?
Thanks.